# Duplicate Data in Fetch record in Three table (Join query) SQL

Tags: mysql

Need to Join four tables in SQL. I have four tables like catch_centerdetails Primary key is catchmasterid ,catch_geardetails, catch_headerdetails, cath_linedetails. Query is excuted but it contains duplicate data. Please help query to avoid the duplicate data.

```
Table 1 

catch_centerdetails 

catchmasterid centername  surveydate    period
1              XXXXX     02-05-20018    morning
2              YYYYY     02-06-20018    evening

Table 2
catch_geardetails

catchmasterid  gearname Total
    1          Gear1        20
    1          Gear2        30
    2          Gear1        20

Table 3 
catch_headerdetails
catchheaderid   catchmasterid   craftname manpower  status
1                      1        DDDD        10        1
2                      1        DDDD        10        1
3                      1        GGGG        5         1
4                      2        HHHH        5         1

Table 4
cath_linedetails
catchlineid catchmasterid    catchheaderid   speciesname  qty
1                   1               1          sp1        10    
2                   1               1          sp2        5 
3                   1               2          sp1        8 
4                   1               2          sp2        7 
5                   1               3          sp1        9 
6                   1               3          sp2        4 
7                   1               4          sp3        4 
8                   1               4          sp4        7 

select ce.catchmasterid,ce.centername,ce.surveydate,ce.period,
ch.craftname,cg.gearname,cl.speciesname,cl.qty 
from catch_centerdetails ce 
INNER JOIN catch_headerdetails ch ON ce.catchmasterid = ch.catchmasterid 
INNER JOIN catch_geardetails cg on cg.catchmasterid = ce.catchmasterid 
Inner Join cath_linedetails cl ON ce.catchmasterid = cl.catchmasterid;
```

Output - Every data repeat 3 times.

Comment: What is your current and expected output?  No one should have to do all the work of setting up a demo just to figure out what the actual question is.

Comment: Instead of select try SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: I used DISTINCT it works in local but it not works in server

Answer (score 0):

You have more that one rows in related table for `catchmasterid` (one-to-many relationship). So when you are joining, you will get multiple records. This is normal and expected.

If you want to get unique records you can use `distinct` like following query, or you need to join with other columns which makes the the related table record unique.

```
select distinct 
       ce.catchmasterid, 
       ce.centername, 
       ce.surveydate, 
       ce.period, 
       ch.craftname, 
       cg.gearname, 
       cl.speciesname, 
       cl.qty 
from catch_centerdetails ce 
       inner join catch_headerdetails ch 
               on ce.catchmasterid = ch.catchmasterid 
       inner join  catch_geardetails cg 
               on cg.catchmasterid = ce.catchmasterid 
       inner join cath_linedetails cl 
               on ce.catchmasterid = cl.catchmasterid;
```

Comment: It comes also duplicate. every data comes 3 times

Comment: It will come multiple times even after using distinct if one of the related value is different, you can check the duplicate rows and you will find the difference in atleast one value. This is the default behaviour when you join one to many data using joins

Comment: inner join cath_linedetails cl  ch.catchheaderid = cl.catchheaderid - Its correct